# .htaccess rewrite rule for trailing slash after .com for backlinks

Tags: .htaccess, hyperlink, url-rewriting, trailing-slash

Backlinks, so links from other pages to my wordpress page, are missing a slash after the .com part. So https://mypage.com/subpage results in https://mypage.comsubpage

This happened after I've changed the domain of a page from .de to .com
Everything else seems to work fine, only those external backlinks to my page are missing the slash.

Tried all different rewrite rules but none worked or even got me a 404.

This is my code:

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[3.2.5]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

https://mypage.comsubpage should result in https://mypage.com/subpage for links from other pages/backlinks. Thanks!

Comment: It seems you need to take a look into the documentation again... This is not how request rewriting works. Request rewriting rewrites _requests_, so _incoming_ requests to a http server, not URLs sent out by some http server. If some "other pages" contain invalid references to your site then there is little you can do about that. Since with those faulty references there is no way that the requests even reach your http server. Simply because a requesting client cannot resolve the host name "mypage.comsubpage" to an IP address.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your comment. The rewrite rules above aren't mine btw. They were already in the .htaccess file. Nothing was wrong with that. Firefox and Safari worked ok, only Chrome was wrong. The mistake was somewhere in my cache of my Chrome browser. After I deleted my cache, everything went fine and the slash was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything ok with the rewrite rules. Obviously the mistake was in my cache of my browser (Chrome). Firefox and Safari worked ok (only found that out after I posted this question, sorry).
After I deleted the cache Chrome went ok and added the slash.

Thanks anyways
Xandru